# image dont display via webpack/scss/background-image

Tags: sass, background-image, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have a strange issue with webpack - **background-image even though a good link (I guese) does't appear**

I have to create simple  with background-image. So in my html I have

```
<div class="logo-full"></div>
```

and my scss file

```
.logo-full{
    background-image: url("../../image/logo-full.png");
    width: 195px;
    height: 195px;
  }
```

my webpack config

*when I specify url like http, everything work great

```
module: {
    loaders: [
       ...
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'},
```

and the result is:

1. webpack successful copy image from directory to /dist folder and rename in on smt like 52ae92bfd5cdfa20dc2167de694b59e1.png
2. in my devtool browser I have correct (I hope) url

   .logo-full {
       background-image: url(52ae92bfd5cdfa20dc2167de694b59e1.png);
   because every compiled file I have directly in /dist folder
3. **but even though of this image is not displayed**

I tried put image on the same level as scss file, tried use '~'. I don't have idea what I doing wrong - please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue today with webpack by

1. Using `{test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},`, over `{test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw'},`
2. Using `file-loader` over `url-loader` for image

Maybe someone didn't figure this out yet :)